# Extending a Generic Collection with another Generic

Tags: java, generics

I need to create my own implementation of a `PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>`

Using my own Interface `MyRunnableInterface` which extends `Runnable`, There are two options I see:

1 - `class MyQueue<T extends MyRunnableInterface> extends PriorityBlockingQueue<T>`

2 - `class MyQueue extends PriorityBlockingQueue<MyRunnableInterface>`

Using option 1, with the constructor `new MyQueue<MyRunnableInterface>` I get the error: *Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyQueue to BlockingQueue*

Using option 1, with the constructor `new MyQueue` I get the warning: *MyQueue is a raw type. References to generic type MyQueue should be parameterized*

Using option 2, with the constructor `new MyQueue` I get the error: *Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyQueue to BlockingQueue*

The thing Is, I want to be able to reference my created MyQueue Object calling a method that takes the Typed parameter `MyRunnableInterface` and not having to do a type cast each time (from T)

I think I'm missing something on the Generics subtlety ?

```
public class MyQueue<T extends MyQueue.MyRunnableInterface>
extends PriorityBlockingQueue<T> {

public interface MyRunnableInterface extends Runnable {

}

public int test( final MyRunnableInterface r ) {
    return 0;
}

private static BlockingQueue<Runnable> create() {
    return new MyQueue<MyRunnableInterface>(); //Error Here
}

private static BlockingQueue<Runnable> create2() {
    return new MyQueue(); //Warning Here
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final BlockingQueue<Runnable> r = create();
    ((MyQueue) r).test(null);
}
```

}

More code added above .... Guess I'll just have to live with the warnings ?

Comment: Which is the *complete* statement? As in `BlockingQUeue bq = new MyQueue<MyRunnableInterface>();`?

Comment: This gives an error:
BlockingQUeue bq = new MyQueue<MyRunnableInterface>();  
 
This is ok, but gives a warning  
BlockingQUeue bq = new MyQueue();

Comment: Your option `1` is how this is usually done; error is probably somewhere in usage. Provide more details about how you use it

Comment: Are you sure `BlockingQueue` is `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue` and not some other type? And taht `PriorityBlockingQueue` is `java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue`? It is the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyQueue<T extends Runnable> extends PriorityBlockingQueue<T> {

    public interface MyRunnableInterface extends Runnable {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final BlockingQueue<MyRunnableInterface> myRunnableInterfaces = new MyQueue<MyQueue.MyRunnableInterface>();
    }
}
```

Works for me...

Comment: Needs to extend PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable> ... I'll update the question with extra code

Comment: The Problem here is that I want to reference the objects as type MyRunnableInterface inside methods in MyQueue

Comment: Yes, that's why I restricted `T` to `extends MyQueue.MyRunnableInterface` in the first version, but you said you *have* to extend `PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>` which binds your subclass to anything extending `Runnable` and therefore the smallest denominator is `Runnable`.

Answer (score 1):

With your updated code, you're getting the error because the generic types are different (related, but the compiler doesn't care). You can do a wildcard match:

```
private static BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable> create() {
    return new MyQueue<MyRunnableInterface>(); //Now no error and no warning
}
```

Comment: This gives an error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from BlockingQueue<capture#1-of ? extends Runnable> to BlockingQueue<Runnable>" on the call to create() ... But I guess I can fix that with a cast

Comment: If you *want* your `BlockingQueue` to be parametrized with `<Runnable>` (I assumed you didn't?, as it's usually better to be as specialized as possible), you can also restrict it in the class defn: `class MyQueue<T extends MyRunnableInterface> extends PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>`, then you don't need the wildcard parameter

Comment: The problem with that format is the overridden methods (e.g. add) need to be parametrized as Runnable not MyRunnableInterface

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the reason one doesn't normally do it that way :)